Name and icon positioning in TabBar from expo-router
I am having trouble with:

Names of my icons are not in one line.  (e.g., "Home" is split into "Hom" and "e").
The icons are partially above the TabBar.

Here is an image of the TabBar that I am working with:

Code:
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import { icons } from '../../constants';

const TabIcon = ({ icon, color, name, focused }) => {
  return (
    <View className="items-center justify-center gap-2">
      <Image
        source={icon}
        resizeMode="contain"
        tintColor={color}
        className="w-6 h-6"
      />
      <Text className={`${focused ? 'font-psemibold' : 'font-pregular'} text-xs`} style={{color: color}}>
        {name}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const TabsLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Tabs
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#FFA001',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#CDCDE0',  
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor:'#161622',
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            borderTopColor:'#232533',
            height:84,
          }        
        }}
      >
        {/* Home Tab */}
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="home"
          options={{
            title: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabIcon icon={icons.home} color={color} name="Home" focused={focused} />
            ),
          }}
        />

        {/* Bookmark Tab */}
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="bookmark"
          options={{
            title: 'Bookmark',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabIcon icon={icons.bookmark} color={color} name="Bookmark" focused={focused} />
            ),
          }}
        />

        {/* Create Tab */}
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="create"
          options={{
            title: 'Create',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabIcon icon={icons.plus} color={color} name="Create" focused={focused} />
            ),
          }}
        />

        {/* Profile Tab */}
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="profile"
          options={{
            title: 'Profile',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabIcon icon={icons.profile} color={color} name="Profile" focused={focused} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tabs>
    </>
  );
};

export default TabsLayout;

Things I've already tried:
I've adjusted the height of the TabBar, but the icons are still partially above it.
How can I fix the alignment of the icons and the text in my TabBar? I would like to make the icon names appear on one line and fix the icon positioning.

i think this will solve your issue:

numberOfLines={1} - Prevent text from splitting into multiple lines
Text.Style - small css fixes



          <Text
        className={`text-xs ${ focused ? 'font-psemibold' : 'font-pregular' }`}
        style={{ color, width: 50,  textAlign: 'center',  }}
        numberOfLines={1}
      > 
</Text>



